# TypeGraphQL: metadataDesignType = reflectedType[parameterIndex] TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Tags: typescript, graphql, typegraphql

I'm studying GraphQL with TypeGraphQL + Typescript. It has a little bit of beauty but I'm getting some trouble with rules of typing.

So, I have the code below:

```
@Resolver(CountryInfo)
export class StaticDataResolver {

    @Query(_returns => [CountryInfo])
    allcountries(@Arg("arg") arg: string) {

        console.log(arg)
    }

    @Query(_returns => [CompleteCountryInfo])
    countryDetails(@Arg("countryId") countryId: string) {


        console.log(countryId)
    }

    @Query(_returns => [StateInfo])
    statesOfCountry(@Arg("countryId") countryId: string){


        console.log(countryId)
    }
}
```

When I run the server I get the error:

```
F:\github\places-api\node_modules\type-graphql\dist\helpers\findType.js:10
        metadataDesignType = reflectedType[parameterIndex];
                                          ^
TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
    at Object.findType (F:\github\places-api\node_modules\type-graphql\dist\helpers\findType.js:10:43)
    at Object.getParamInfo (F:\github\places-api\node_modules\type-graphql\dist\helpers\params.js:9:49)
    at F:\github\places-api\node_modules\type-graphql\dist\decorators\Arg.js:9:159
    at F:\github\places-api\src\graphql\resolvers\static-data.resolver.ts:9:37
    at DecorateProperty (F:\github\places-api\node_modules\reflect-metadata\Reflect.js:553:33)
    at Object.decorate (F:\github\places-api\node_modules\reflect-metadata\Reflect.js:123:24)
    at __decorate (F:\github\places-api\src\graphql\resolvers\static-data.resolver.ts:4:92)
    at Object.<anonymous> (F:\github\places-api\src\graphql\resolvers\static-data.resolver.ts:12:5)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1158:30)
    at Module.m._compile (F:\github\places-api\node_modules\ts-node\src\index.ts:806:23)
```

I don't know what's wrong with my code, so if anyone has the answer it'll be welcome! =]

Answer (score 1):

Try to set `emitDecoratorMetadata: true` in your `tsconfig.json`.
It helped me resolve this trouble.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using babel without proper TypeScript metadata reflections plugin.

Please checkout this issue:
https://github.com/MichalLytek/type-graphql/issues/55